# JS Noob: use JavaScript 'for loop' to match a variable to a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, html

The title explains it pretty well, but I'm trying to build a 'for loop' that matches a variable (in this case, one garnered by an HTML5 form) to a value in a cell in a 2-column database. Then I want to 'console.log' the value in the adjacent (next column over) cell.

Looking for coding help and any suggestions for what type of database would work best with this type of arrangement.

```
var myDB = {AA:100, BB:50, CC:75, DD:66, EE:40};
function DB(value) {
    return myDB[value];
}
console.log(DB('AA'));
```

Comment: what have you tried up to this point? if you want support please give us a code sample

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Are you using html5 localStorage or what?

Comment: sorry for violating 'rule #1' - bush league move. I was trying all sorts of crazy stuff, none was as simple or elegant as below. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the best approach for this would be to have a data structure like this:

```
var myDB = {
    'key1' : 'value1'
}
```

This would remove the need for a "for loop" as you were planning to use which is incredibly inefficient and would enable you to use a simple index check like this:

```
function getValue( index ) {
    if( typeof myDB[index] == 'undefined' ) return false;
    return myDB[index];
}
```

If you need to be able to search on either index, then you'll need to make a slightly more complex database layout (I'm assuming your "database" is actually just javascript data since you wanted to console.log the data.

If you're looking to do this in a server side database and return the data, you'll need AJAX functionality and server side APIs to post those ajax requests to and return your data in JSON. Which is slightly more complicated than what I just suggested above.

Update:

If you wanted to "search" the database values and find the matching key, you would probably have to either run a for loop on the myDB object, or build your database a little differently by having a separate object for each of the keys and one for the data. Something like this:

```
var myDB = {
    'key1' : {
        'value1':0,
        'value2':1
     },
    'key2' : {
        'value1':0,
        'value2':1
    },
    'data' : {
        0:'data_for_record_1',
        1:'data_for_record_2'
    }
}
```

Now you can "search" on either of the index columns and get the ID of the data row that corresponds to that matched column. This data structure is very similar to how indexes are used in most databases like MySQL and others. So your "search" function would likely look something like this:

```
function searchDB( index , value ) {
    if( typeof myDB[index][value] == 'undefined' ) return false;
    if( typeof myDB.data[myDB[index][value]] == 'undefined' ) return false;
    return myDB.data[myDB[index][value]];
}
```

Comment: Because `undefined` and `false` are both falsey this isn't much better than just doing `myDB[index]` and skipping the `getValue()` function altogether right?

Comment: That's not how the typeof statement works. It will return 'undefined' if the index does not exist. Javascript isn't as forgiving as other languages. If you do if( myDB[index] ) and the index isn't set, you will trigger a JS error and the script will halt.

Comment: That's not true, but if `myDB` doesn't exist it will fail. Hence why `window.console && console.log("bla bla bla");` is a valid way to not break browsers that don't support the console object.

Comment: You can check for properties on objects, but you cannot access properties of non-existent properties (`myDB[index].prop`) or try and call them as functions without throwing errors.

Comment: Yeah you're correct there. I was thinking ahead to the edit I just made to my OP. In that scenario you need the check first. But that's a data structure which would be very searchable in JS using as many indexes of the data as you wanted to have really.

Comment: thanks for your help, so far, I've ended up simplifying your code quite a bit, but with the same functionality, see above.